# Shuffling a list in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I'm in a basic Python programming class, and I am stuck. We have to Generate index values i and j in the appropriate range by using the length of the list, not a
hard-coded number, and make sure that the list elements are swapped only if it brings the list closer to sorted order, lowest to the highest from the left.

So far I have:

```
from random import*

def main():
    LENGTH= 25
    shuffleList= 1000
    numList= [0] * LENGTH

    for num in range(0,len(numList)):
        rand= randint(-100,100)
        numList[num] += rand
    print("List before shuffling:")
    print numList  

    for i in range(0, len(numList)):
        min = i
        shuffleList += 1

    for j in range(-1, len(numList)):
        shuffleList +=1
```

Now I just have no idea what to do from this point on. Thanks.

Comment: Please, indent your code properly

Comment: Python code without proper indentation is not python. Lexically speaking not even going to sematics. So there is no way to understand what you posted. Anyway, you might wanna look at `random.shuffle`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `random.shuffle`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
LENGTH=25
random_list = numpy.random.randint(-100,100,LENGTH) #Generate random list
for i in range(random_list): # for each index in list as i
    for j in range(random_list): # for each index in list as j
        if lrandom_listst[i] > random_list[j]: # if we should swap
           random_list[i],random_list[j] = random_list[j],random_list[i] # do swap
```

this is not a very good algorithm to sort a list ... maybe thats the point

Comment: Yes he says we will learn a better algorithm later, but for now we'll use this one!

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful: http://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/

Or maybe something like this: (Pseodocode Credit: Wikipdia)

```
for i from n−1 downto 1 do
 j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
 exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "more ordered" you simply mean that the left hand side ascends to the right hand side. An easy way to do that would simply be to select two random indices, compare them, and switch them if the left hand side is higher.

I can compress this function quite a bit, but in order to give you a better understanding, I left it in its more verbose form:

```
import random

def check_sort(items, predicate=lambda x, y: x <= y):
    return all(predicate(items[i],items[i+1]) for i in range(len(items)-1))

numbers = [i for i in range(0, 100)]
random.shuffle(numbers)
changes = 0
generations = 0
while not check_sort(numbers):
    generations += 1
    x, y = random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1), random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1)
    x, y = (x, y) if x > y else (y, x)
    if numbers[x] < numbers[y]:
        changes += 1
        tmp = numbers[y]
        numbers[y] = numbers[x]
        numbers[x] = tmp

print("Generations: {}\nChanges: {}".format(generations, changes))
```